# Send image via post from App Inventor to Orion

Tags: fiware, app-inventor, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to send a picture via POST to orion after captured using camera, but I'm suffering with the lack of information about how could I do that using App Inventor.

Anyone knows how to send it via webservice to Orion or even to MongoDb?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `web` component and its `PostFile` method, see also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#Web).
Then follow their API documentation (my guess is, there is an API documentation available?) and put together the `Url` and `RequestHeaders`, see also my [Dropbox example](https://puravidaapps.com/dropbox.php) and [How to use the PostFile block in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php).

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Hi Taifun, thanks for your reply! I have followed your post before, but I haven't find any information (documentation or examples on the web) about how to package an image inside a POST to send to a server.

Comment: as already said, use the `PostFile` method, there is no such thing as 'package an image inside a POST'...

Answer (score 2):

The only option to store a picture in Orion would be to convert it to a data URL. I would not recommend to do so though. You can always store the picture in an object storage and keep a URL in Orion which can allow you to retrieve the picture when needed.